# Gaalsien vs. Coalition: How to counter a Coalition Nuke rush?

Tags: homeworld-deserts-of-kharak

People online are saying Coalition is stronger than Gaalsien, and I'm beginning to agree. I played 5 matches as Gaalsien and lost every one against my friend, then I played 1 match as Coalition against him and won immediately. Every game we played the same strategy.

Turret rush, follow with tanks

Then Nukes as fast as possible.

Battle Cruisers to close the game.

All we do is place turrets on resource so they Gaalsien can't expand
Then rush nuke and nuke a resource line everytime nuke cooldown comes up. Meanwhile just walk towards their crippled lines with carrier + a few battle cruiser and end the game. 3 Battle cruisers will destroy the Gaalsien carrier in about 5 seconds. If he flees, just mow down his resources and chase and win. Counter any sanskimmer rushes with tanks

I see no way around this strategy.
How do you counter nukes? You can't dodge them fast enough usually, you can't shoot them out of the air, cruise missile counter attack isn't good enough because they can just dodge it.

I think the game is broken.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently I was right that this strategy is "unbeatable", but I was wrong that the game is broken. This was an intentional design, and it makes sense.

Talking with the discord group, they made it clear that once nukes have been researched, you've already lost the game. They basically said that Gaalsien has to use their production cruisers in an aggressive, forward stance, using harrasment, to force the Coalition to choose between:

- pouring money into nuke technology (which is expensive and takes forever) and lose the game to harrasment,
- or switch off and get back into a level playing field.

In other words, if you sit back and let the Coalition tech up, instead of forcing them to build military, they will win the late game, which makes sense because Gaalsien IS the "faster" race.

Also, if they DO build nukes, and choose to hit your econ, immediately rush them with your standing army because that's 600 used to hit econ and your military can't get nuked for awhile, so you know they should be weak for a bit. Also, never group your army in a bunch if you see them teching towards nukes, for obvious reasons. Split into 2

Answer (score 0):

The coalition can use the same forward deployment with just their carrier.  The Gaal forward deployment advantage from Production Cruisers vanishes 5 mins in when they need to be pulled from the front line for economic expansion.  Many coalition units also have superior speed to Gaal units and all are cheaper.  Although the lower cost is in line with the spirit of the game (gaal units are meant to have superior technology, faster, self repair etc.) the benefits of the higher quality Gaal units are hard to capitalize on if your opponent is savvy and aggressive in limiting your "Hit and Run" tactics.

The game was not engineered to be an auto loss once a coalition player gets a nuke and the cost for a Gaal player to upgrade his carrier is the same as a coalition player.  The thinking behind this is silly, the fact is that currently the game is imbalanced and favors coalition factions.  However, nukes can be directly countered by superior unit dispersion and positioning, this requires multiple control groups and is more micro intensive but will severely cripple the extreme coalition advantage in this regard. (gaal missile barrage is luck driven)

Lastly for the turret rush that is so often effective on newer players.  once you spot it put one power into carrier speed and move it to the advancing baserunner/turret location.  Bring back your forward PC to collect resources from your main.  This coalition opening forces early map control but yields no resource advantage if handles properly.  Your carrier will completely shutdown any early turret aggression.  Hope this helps, I am really getting tired of seeing this cheese.

Comment: Turret cheese is so common I just assume it always and nowadays I got pretty good at shutting it down. Gaal skimmer rush can be reallyl good too, just don't lose them (retreat when they falter)